# CakePHP Model::saveMany, excluding an array if empty?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I want to 2 or more rows in my database.  I originally tried

```
$this->[model]->save($data)
```

but ran into errors, so then came across:

Model::saveMany @ http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

The save works fine, my problem is with combining arrays that aren't blank so that it actually works.

What I am doing is as follows:

```
    if($thingone == "1"){
         $data = array('somevalue' => 'value')
    }

    if($thingtwo == "1"){
        $data2 = array('somevalue' => 'anothervalue') 
    }

    $insertdata = array($data, $data2)


 $this->[Model]->saveMany($insertdata);
```

It works, but only if $thingone and $thingtwo are both equal to 1.  Not sure how to go about doing this?  If one of the '$things' is not '1' (meaning I don't want it included), it won't insert any records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

```
$insertdata = array();
if($thingone == "1"){
     $insertdata[] = array('somevalue' => 'value')
}

if($thingtwo == "1"){
    $insertdata[] = array('somevalue' => 'anothervalue') 
}

$this->[Model]->saveMany($insertdata);
```

Comment: beautiful.  works perfectly.  crazy how obvious it is after seeing it :D.  thank you!